# Run a java application in background on Debian with logback and nohup

Tags: java, linux, logging, logback, slf4j

I have some apps that are packaged as executable jar files. Now I added logback logging with file appender to the app. The problem is I run those apps on server with this command:

```
nohup java -jar app.jar &
```

nohup.out captures all outputs and ruins the whole purpose of rotating log files and separate error and info log.
I'd rather not to run my app as a service (There are lots of it) so wondering if there is a way to execute the jar in the background infinitely and have the logback logging to the files defined in logback.xml
This is my logback.xml file if it helps:

```xml
<configuration debug="true">

    <appender name="FILE-ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/home/user/logs/kafka/orders/kafka-consumer.info.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>
            <maxHistory>200</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-ROLLING-ERROR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/home/user/logs/kafka/orders/kafka-consumer.error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>
            <maxHistory>200</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} %m%n%ex{100}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="kafkaLogger" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="kafkaLoggerError" level="error" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING-ERROR"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING-ERROR"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: post your logback.xml

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I added logback.xml file. Does it really help?

Comment: you need to pass the logback configuration ...

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the configuration file to the logback system.

```
 nohup java -jar app.jar -DLogback.configurationFile=/path/to/Logback.xml &
```

Comment: Shall I provide logback.xml outside of jar file somewhere on the file system and point the DLogback.configuration to its path?

Comment: I did this and still all the logs are diverted to the nohup.out file.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the ways to do this is something like this:

```
nohup setsid java -jar app.jar -Dparams=xyz </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: This avoids making nohup.out file but no log file gets created.

Comment: @Hessam: Well, you have to fix your LogBack config.